# Redirect with flash data in laravel 5 does not work

Tags: php, html, redirect, laravel-5.1

When I submit a form I want to redirect back to the current view/blade with some data:

here is my redirect:

```
return redirect('configbeacon')->with('requirement', 'req');
```

here is my blade where I check if 'requirement' is set:

```
@if(Session::has('requirement'))
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                Dit tilbud blev gemt
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div>
        @endif
```

But it does not show the elements inside the if loop... Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you're hitting your redirect line? You could `dd` right before it to confirm.

Comment: thank for your respons. I have tried dd befor redirect and the application die and dump.

Comment: What if you put a `dump(Session::has('requirement'));` in the controller method? Does it have it immediately after redirecting?

Comment: I had the same issue, turns out it was because I wasn't logged in to my application, so a session never started, maybe that is the issue?